# Display string over a recognizable region of a picture

Tags: java, image-processing, image-recognition

I am currently trying to create an animated mascot for an application, and to keep the animator's job simple, I'd like my application to be able to display text over images like the following template, with the right transformations:

[image]

The string should be displayed over the board the mascot is holding, with the right transformation, according to the four red dots.

How should I proceed?

Comment: This guy seems to like it when buses fall on his head.

Comment: So you want to display actual text on top of an animated image? The chances of you keeping your text (size/scale/rotation/transformation/skewing/...) perfectly in sync with the animated image is highly unlikely.  Why not just have the animator add the text into the animation?

Comment: because the text will be determined by the application itself. I guess I'll replace "text" by "string" to make it clearer.

Comment: have you tried to display your mascot within your application? if yes, provide this code snippet and we can help you on your quest...